# Running Nginx in GitHub Action results in 'Permission denied' error

Tags: nginx, github-actions

I'm running on [ubuntu-2204](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md) in GitHub Action to set up a simple web server using Nginx. I want to use Nginx as a reverse proxy to send requests to the backend PHP-FPM. However, when I set the root directive to [$GITHUB_WORKSPACE](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables#:%7E:text=in%20the%20repository.-,GITHUB_WORKSPACE,-The%20default%20working), it doesn't work as expected. I have created a [sample repository](https://github.com/Gasol/gh-action-playground/actions/runs/3815377892/jobs/6490328178) to demonstrate the problem. Even when serving a static index.html without PHP-FPM configuration. it still can't be found and returns an HTTP 404 error.

```
    Run curl -vf localhost
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Sun, 01 Jan 2023 05:15:29 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 162
< Connection: keep-alive
* The requested URL returned error: 404
```

The log generated by Nginx says:

```
2023/01/01 05:15:29 [crit] 2025#2025: *1 stat() "/home/runner/work/gh-action-playground/gh-action-playground/public/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2023/01/01 05:15:29 [crit] 2025#2025: *1 stat() "/home/runner/work/gh-action-playground/gh-action-playground/public/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

The problem seems to be a common permission issue. I created an action called Fix permission to try to fix it.

```
- name: Fix permission
        run: |
          sudo usermod -aG docker www-data
          sudo chown -R www-data:www-data ${{ github.workspace }}
          sudo chmod -R 777 public
          sudo -u www-data bash -c 'cd ${{ github.workspace }}/public; pwd; whoami'
          sudo -u www-data stat /home/runner/work/gh-action-playground/gh-action-playground/public
          sudo -u www-data stat /home/runner/work/gh-action-playground/gh-action-playground
          sudo -u www-data stat /home/runner/work/gh-action-playground
          sudo -u www-data stat /home/runner/work
          sudo -u www-data stat /home/runner
          sudo -u www-data stat /home
          sudo -u www-data stat /
          echo '<h1>test</h1>' >> public/index.html
          echo "::group::debug"
          ls -al
          ls -al ../
          ls -al ../../
          ls -al ../../../
          df -h
          ps auxwww
          mount
          echo "::endgroup::"
```

but it failed. The output of the failed job can be found at https://github.com/Gasol/gh-action-playground/actions/runs/3815377892/jobs/6490328178.
As you can see, the root is set to `/home/runner/work/gh-action-playground/gh-action-playground/public`, which is the correct location of the index.html file.

I'm using the following script to ensure that the www-data user have permission to change directory to the root directory of the virtual server.

```
sudo -u www-data bash -c 'cd ${{ github.workspace }}/public; pwd; whoami'
```

The output was correct as the following.

```
/home/runner/work/gh-action-playground/gh-action-playground/public
www-data
```

The `ps` command shows the nginx was running as the `www-data` user

```
root        2024  0.0  0.0  81896  2176 ?        Ss   05:15   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
www-data    2025  0.0  0.0  82652  6608 ?        S    05:15   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    2026  0.0  0.0  82652  6608 ?        S    05:15   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

The interesting part is that [it works](https://github.com/Gasol/gh-action-playground/actions/runs/3812334815/jobs/6485484839) when I move the root directory to /var/html/public. So, why can't Nginx access the index.html file in the $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/public directory? What's the difference between $GITHUB_WORKSPACE and /var/html/public?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Nginx is unable to access the $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/public directory due to a lack of permissions. The error message (13: Permission denied) suggests that Nginx does not have the necessary permissions to access the directory.

The difference between $GITHUB_WORKSPACE and /var/html/public is that $GITHUB_WORKSPACE is the root directory of the repository that is currently being built in the GitHub Action, while /var/html/public is a directory on your system. It's likely that Nginx has the necessary permissions to access /var/html/public, but not $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/public.

To fix the issue, you can try giving Nginx the necessary permissions to access the $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/public directory. You can do this by running the following command:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/public
```

This will give read and execute permissions to all users for all files and directories in the $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/public directory.

Alternatively, you can try changing the ownership of the $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/public directory to the user that Nginx is running as. You can do this by running the following command:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/public
```

Comment: Your suggestion is not working. Please see the workflow file to see what I have done.

Comment: did you update Fix permission to this?


     - name: Fix permission
       run: |
         sudo chown -R www-data:www-data $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/public
    sudo chmod -R 755 $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/public

Comment: I have already done that in the action "Fix permission". Please read the question carefully.

          sudo chown -R www-data:www-data ${{ github.workspace }}
          sudo chmod -R 777 public

Comment: this code is not the same

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that changes to filesystem permissions don't take effect immediately, and that restarting relevant services is necessary for the changes to take effect (Check out [this job](https://github.com/Gasol/gh-action-playground/actions/runs/3820000352/jobs/6497993665) for an example to fix). This seems unusual to me.

I also asked about [this behavior](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/discussions/6859) in a GitHub discussion, but I'll leave that topic for there.